# Error when from flask_uploads import UploadSet,configure_uploads, IMAGES

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug, flask-uploads

I received error when i just to try to import UploadSet,configure_uploads, IMAGES from flask uploads.

i don't do any other steps yet

just i save file i received this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\login\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    from flask_uploads import UploadSet,configure_uploads, IMAGES
  File "C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask_uploads.py", line 26, in <module>
    from werkzeug import secure_filename, FileStorage
ImportError: cannot import name 'secure_filename' from 'werkzeug' (C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you install `Flask-Uploads` from PyPI by e.g. `pip install Flask-Uploads` you get an outdated version.

In February 2020 there was a breaking change in `Werkzeug` - thus your error message.

Unfortunately, the author of `Flask-Uploads` decided against releasing a new version for PyPI.

As an alternative, you can use `Flask-Reuploaded`. This package works as a drop-in-replacement, so you do even do not have to change a single line of code.

https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Reuploaded/

https://github.com/jugmac00/flask-reuploaded